# Moving chrome window to another monitor turns it black

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, windows-10

Since upgrading to windows 10 Whenever I move a chrome window to my external monitor from my laptop monitor my chrome goes black. It only happens when the chrome window is maximized and I currently have to restore window, drag to 2nd monitor, drop, then maximize in order to have a working chrome. Any suggestions?

Here is a picture of my chrome bug:

[image]

Comment: try to turn the HW acceleration in chrome settings off. Also look if you use the latest GPU drivers

Comment: That worked Magicandre, but I can't figure out how to select your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such graphic glitches are often causes by GPU issues. Make sure you use the latest GPU driver for your GPU and if you already use the latest driver, [disable the hardware acceleration](http://www.solveyourtech.com/turn-hardware-acceleration-google-chrome/) in the Chrome settings:

[image]

Comment: I've had a similar issue on Firefox, which I solved using the same method as [magicandre1981's answer](https://superuser.com/a/985368/579200) by disabling hardware acceleration (set `gfx.direct2d.disabled` and `layers.acceleration.disabled` to `true` in `about:config` as suggested [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1106854)). (I would have posted this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: It's specific pages for me. LIke if I visit metlife.com and click "Log in" that triggers it, only on one particular monitor. (I have a dual monitor setup).

Answer (score 4):

Pressing F11 twice to go fullscreen and back solves the problem temporarily.
Pressing CTRL + SHIFT + WIN + B (shortcut for reset graphics drivers) solves the problem better.

Comment: I tried disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and restarting (per @magicandre1981's answer), but to no avail. Both of these work-arounds work well. Thank you!