# Visual Studio dialog box becomes "blank" after dragging it to a different screen

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I open a Visual Studio 2015 dialog on one screen:

[image]

and then try to drag it to another screen, the dialog box becomes completely black:

[image]

If I drag it back to the original screen, however, it's displayed normally again.

Has anyone experienced this before? What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I've experienced similar.  Have you ensured you're using the latest video drivers for your system?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I gave it a try, my driver was, in fact, out of date, doesn't seem to have fixed the problem though unfortunately

Comment: have you tried SW rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a graphic card issue. Visual Studio is coded with WPF, which uses DirectX.

Open VS and go into the options and disable the entry `automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance` and next disable `Use hardware graphics acceleration if possible`

[image]

Now Visual Studio uses software based rendering. Turning HW acceleration off, also [fixes such issues in other tools like Chrome](https://superuser.com/a/985368/174557).

Comment: Thank you so much - this seems to have fixed the problem